Reports are greyed out (vivado)
Trying to create a project for application of TCAM (Ternary Content Addressable Memory) for networking.
Need to analyze the working and performance of a TCAM in Vivado ,
Code for the TCAM is taken from this github : https://github.com/mcjtag/tcam
Wrote a testbench for it, have added the code later in this post.
While trying to access reports, I saw that some reports were greyed out (Mostly Timing related). Wanted to know the reason for this , image has been attached below

Is it due to my testbench?
Testbench is as follows
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module tb_tcam;

// Parameters
parameter ADDR_WIDTH = 4;
parameter KEY_WIDTH = 4;
parameter DATA_WIDTH = 4;
parameter MASK_DISABLE = 1;         // Disable masking for now
parameter RAM_STYLE_DATA = "block"; // Simple Dual Port Memory for data table
parameter REQUEST_LATENCY = 3;      // Define request latency of 3 cycles

// Inputs
reg clk;
reg rst;
reg [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] set_addr;
reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] set_data;
reg [KEY_WIDTH-1:0] set_key;
reg [KEY_WIDTH-1:0] set_xmask;
reg set_clr;
reg set_valid;
reg [KEY_WIDTH-1:0] req_key;
reg req_valid;

// Outputs
wire req_ready;
wire [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] res_addr;
wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] res_data;
wire res_valid;
wire res_null;

// Instantiate the TCAM module
tcam #(
    .ADDR_WIDTH(ADDR_WIDTH),
    .KEY_WIDTH(KEY_WIDTH),
    .DATA_WIDTH(DATA_WIDTH),
    .MASK_DISABLE(MASK_DISABLE),
    .RAM_STYLE_DATA(RAM_STYLE_DATA)
) tcam_inst (
    .clk(clk),
    .rst(rst),
    .set_addr(set_addr),
    .set_data(set_data),
    .set_key(set_key),
    .set_xmask(set_xmask),
    .set_clr(set_clr),
    .set_valid(set_valid),
    .req_key(req_key),
    .req_valid(req_valid),
    .req_ready(req_ready),
    .res_addr(res_addr),
    .res_data(res_data),
    .res_valid(res_valid),
    .res_null(res_null)
);

// Clock generation
always #5 clk = ~clk;  // 10ns clock period (100 MHz)

// Declare loop variable outside for loop
reg [3:0] i; // Declare loop variable as a 4-bit register to handle values 0-15

// Initialize test entries in the TCAM
initial begin
    // Initialize inputs
    clk = 0;
    rst = 1;
    set_addr = 0;
    set_data = 0;
    set_key = 0;
    set_xmask = 0;
    set_clr = 0;
    set_valid = 0;
    req_key = 0;
    req_valid = 0;

    // Reset the TCAM
    #10 rst = 0;

    // Set 16 entries in the TCAM
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1) begin
            set_key = i[KEY_WIDTH-1:0];    // Set keys from 0000 to 1111
            set_addr = i[ADDR_WIDTH-1:0];  // Address: match key
            set_data = i[DATA_WIDTH-1:0];  // Data: same as key for simplicity
            set_valid = 1;                 // Signal to set entry
        #10 set_valid = 0;                 // Wait for entry to be written
    end

    // Begin generating requests as a bitstream with enforced 3-cycle latency
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 1) begin
        // Issue a request
        #5 req_key = i[KEY_WIDTH-1:0]; // Use keys from 0000 to 1111
           req_valid = 1;
        #5 req_valid = 0; // Deassert req_valid to trigger search

        // Wait 3 cycles for the TCAM search latency before issuing next request
        #30; // Enforce 3-cycle delay
    end
    
    #10000 $finish; // End simulation after 10,000 ns (10 sec)
end

// Monitor each request for match/no-match
always @(posedge clk) begin
    // Log each request key as it's checked
    if (req_valid && req_ready) begin
        $display("Requesting key: %b", req_key);
    end

    // Display match result if res_valid is high
    if (res_valid) begin
        if (res_null)
            $display("No match found for key %b at time %t", req_key, $time);
        else
            $display("Match found for key %b at address %d with data %d at time %t", req_key, res_addr, res_data, $time);
    end
end

endmodule

How do I correct this ?
